# How to set CCAvenue redirect_url or cancel_url in Shopify?

Tags: android, react-native, shopify, ccavenue, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I'm building a **React Native (Android)** application with **Shopify**. I'm facing some issue with *CCAvenue* payment process. For the payment process I'm using [WebURL](https://github.com/Shopify/js-buy-sdk)

Whenever *CCAVenue* transaction fails users get redirect to 404 page. To avoid this, I need to catch whenever *CCAvenue* transaction gets failed or canceled.

By looking at *CAvenue*C doc I'm seeing some parameter e.g **redirect_url** and **cancel_url** that could help in my case but I'm not seeing any option to set same at Shopify(my store) Dashboard.

Could you please help me here or suggest if we have any different approach?

Thanks.